# Multisite Installation: how do I setup global search?

Tags: multisite, search, globals

I run a multisite installation and my sites are bilingual. I would like to find out how I can setup global search.

Are there decent plugins available that do this? Cos I'm a wordpress noob and am deathly afraid of doing stuff like changing/editing php files because I worry that a single error may cause my entire site to breakdown...

I did a search and saw this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-global-search/

But it is an old plugin and hasn't been updated for a couple of years. Plus, reviews are mixed so I'm wondering if there's a better solution/plugin that I haven't found yet..

Would really appreciate your advice and help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do it is to index all the posts and search through them in database. This method should be the fastest when you perform a search because you can filter posts, create the pagination etc. Check this tutorial https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/search-across-wp-multisite.html

Another way is to to something with `switch_to_blog()` function – I mean to search each site individually and then to rearrange the results, but I suppose it would be a very slow code. Especially if you have a lot of site in your network.