# Make Wordpress Search for Both Main Domain and Subdomain

Tags: multisite, database, search

I have check through Stackexchange, but no topic is similar to this topic to this.

Is there any way to make WordPress search work for both main site and subdomain?

Both of them have two separate databases.

Comment: You mean subdomain? Yes, there are questions here e.g. [Multisite Installation: how do I setup global search?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/312442/multisite-installation-how-do-i-setup-global-search), and I've seen one about doing this with ElasticPress too: [ElasticPress Indexing multiple sites](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/332644/elasticpress-indexing-multiple-sites). Plus if you search for 'wordpress multisite search' there are some plugins too (although I haven't tried them so can't recommend them).

Comment: I'm assuming you mean a subdomain, right? And is it a multisite or not? Probably not, if the databases are separate.

Comment: its NOT a multisite, its just a single wp installation.

Comment: Two single WP installations? I suspect some of these will still just work, e.g. a shared ElasticPress index between the two. Multisites are separate databases anyway but all accessed through the same connection, whereas if you need separate database connections then either both sites need both sets of connection details, or you need to get one to search against the other one's REST API then stitch the results together, or use some other shared external index I guess.